# Is the perception of time absolute?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time, perception

If there is a place where no changes or movements can be observed, can the time be perceived there?

Comment: Perception is a tricky thing which often goes beyond physics into philosophy.  In particular, there is an outstanding question in philosophy about whether time can advance without the objects in the universe changing.  To turn this philosophy question into a physics question, you would need to change the term "percieved" into something which can be measured using science.

Comment: sure, your thoughts flow on time

Comment: No measurement is absolute, all of them compares things together. If you don't have anything which a known length, you can't measure length. Your world doesn't have anything with an absolute tike, so you can't measure time. Although your question looks to me more phylosophical.

Comment: Perception needs the observer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about psychology not physics.